# Adding a context menu to a shape using FXML

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I am trying to add a context menu to a circle element using JavaFX 2 FXML.
Adding the menu in code works perfectly, adding it in FXML does not work.

FXML:

```
 <Circle fx:id="connectionStatusCircle" fill="#ff6666" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="11.0" radius="8.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE">
      <contextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
              <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unspecified Action" />
              </items>
          </ContextMenu>
      </contextMenu>
</Circle>
```

The thrown exception is:

> > *Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid property.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Circle it is not possible to add Context Menu in FXMl at designing because its not defined in the property of circle so you have to it pragmatically .

try this-----

```
cm  =new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem a = new MenuItem("A");
    MenuItem b = new MenuItem("B");
    MenuItem c = new MenuItem("C");
    cm.getItems().addAll(a,b,c);
    circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            if(t.getButton().toString().equals("SECONDARY"))
           cm.show(circle,t.getScreenX(),t.getSceneY());
        }
    });
```